# Разместить кнопку Submit выше полей формы

Tags: html, javascript

Тривиальная проблема, есть форма HTML, в конце формы кнопка сабмит.

Необходимо кнопку разместить вверху форму, в начале страницы (для удобства).

**Решение может быть:** применение CSS позиционирования, что геморно, и навешивание js события отправки формы.
Есть другие варианты?

Comment: И можно пример простой с JS

Comment: <input type='button' onclick="document.forms[0].sumbit();">

Comment: а что мешает этот сабмит перед полями поставить в разметке ? ещё, можно `<label for="buttonid">жми меня</label>` но я не уверен в кошерности такого решения для случая  когда label вне формы.

[в общем-то работает](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/6jgU8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Атрибуту идентификатора формы присвоить значение:

```
<form id="example"> ...
```

Кнопка, расположенная **вне формы**, может иметь такие атрибуты:

```html
<button
  type="submit"
  form="example" <!-- Форма, с которой связана кнопка. -->
  formaction="/page" <!-- Переопределяет атрибут `action` формы. -->
  formmethod="get" <!-- Переопределяет атрибут `method` формы. -->
>Отправить</button>
```

Список доступных атрибутов тега [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes).

---

Таким образом, форма может иметь несколько кнопок для отправки, как внутри, так и за её пределами:

```html
<form id="example" action="page.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="field" value="" />
  <button type="submit" name="send">Отправить</button>
</form>

<button form="example" type="submit" name="send_other">Послать</button>
```

Comment: Это HTML5?
Ранее не знал о formaction и formmethod

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk да, [поддержка IE>=10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)