# Как обратиться к элементу вне формы?

Tags: javascript, php

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, которая находится в форме, создавалась другая кнопка при нажатии на которую появлялось бы слово.

```
<form class="form" action="home.php" method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="make_todo" class="make_todo">+</button>
</form>
```

PHP

```
$data = $_POST;

if( isset($data['make_todo']) ) {
    echo '<button type="submit" form="form" name="make" placeholder="Вывести"></button>';

    if ( isset($data['make']) ) {
        echo "string";
    }
}
```

Comment: Начните с этого [Изолирование PHP от HTML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode) и воспользуйтесь конструкцией `<?php if (...)): ?>` внутри формы, если вам нужно добавление/замена кнопки с перезагрузкой страницы.

Comment: Надо точнее сформулировать, что вы хотите. Если это надо сделать без перезагрузки страницы, то все делается средствами javascript. На кнопку формы можно добавить обработчик события нажатия, который будет создавать другую кнопку. "появлялось бы слово" - тем же javascript можно менять текст у элементов.

Comment: Я хочу чтобы та кнопка, которую я создал была в форме, но form="form", не работает

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Разместить кнопку Submit выше полей формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/310502/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-submit-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0):

Чуть переписал Ваш код, если правильно Вас понял то можно так сделать.
Но тут может быть много подводных камней, например ссылку сразу могут дёрнуть и попасть на любой шаг сразу.

(Если нужно что бы без перезагрузки работало надо javascript использовать)

```
<?
// файл home.php
$data = $_POST;

if(!isset($data['make'])) {?>

    <form class="form" action="home.php" method="POST">

        <?if( isset($data['make_todo']) ) { ?>
            <button type="submit" form="form" name="make" placeholder="Вывести"></button>
        <?}else{ ?>
            <button type="submit" name="make_todo" class="make_todo">+</button>
        <?}?>

    </form>
<?}else{?>
     string
<?}
```